# Implementing the arrow keys in solar systems openGL program

Tags: c, opengl, glut

As part of my solar systems program everything is implemented fine and word, i tried to expand my program to include that user can fly around the orrey or in other word, take a view from a spaceship which fly through space by using the arrow keys. This is what I basically did:

```
   void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
    {
      switch (key)
      {
        case 27:  /* Escape key */
                 exit(0);
                 break;
        case (GLUT_KEY_LEFT): lon += TURN_ANGLE;
                              if(lon == 360)
                                lon = 0;
                  break;
        case (GLUT_KEY_RIGHT):
                              lon -= TURN_ANGLE;
                  if(lon == -360)
                               lon = 0;
                  break;
        case (GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP): 
                              if(lat  + TURN_ANGLE <= 90)
                               lat += TURN_ANGLE;
                              break;
        case (GLUT_KEY_UP):   eyex += sin(DEG_TO_RAD * (lon)) * RUN_SPEED;
                              eyez += cos(DEG_TO_RAD * (lon)) * RUN_SPEED;
                              break;
        case (GLUT_KEY_DOWN): eyex -= sin(DEG_TO_RAD * (lon)) * RUN_SPEED;
                              eyez -= cos(DEG_TO_RAD * (lon)) * RUN_SPEED;
                              break;
        default: break;


      }
    }
```

where `lat` and `lon` are global angles used together with the current eye point(`eyex`, `eyey`, `eyez`), and 
`RUN_SPEED` distance to step in the XZ plane. I dont know why this part is not working even though i didn't get any error in this part everything compile file but the arrow keys are not working. Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

With `glutKeyboardFunc()` you can only capture simple ASCII letters, in order to respond to the rest of the keys you need to setup a separate event handler: [`glutSpecialFunc()`](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node54.html).

Note that the signature of the special handler changes a bit:

```
void special(int key, int x, int y)
{
  switch (key)
  {
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT: lon += TURN_ANGLE;
                          if(lon == 360)
                            lon = 0;
              break;
    /* ... */
    default: break;
  }
}
```

Remember that this special handler does **not** replace the keyboard handler you've been using, it just complements it.

Comment: unfortunatelly bor ... it's not working even first time escape key was working but when i tried ur method with glutspecialfun() it's not working and so others ... is there something else i missed, cause in main i include glutKeyboardFunc (keyboard); which is obvious i have to call it .So with glutspecialfun() non off the keys working but with glutKeyboardFunc only escape key is working and others are not. any clue or help.plz?

Comment: `glutSpecialFunc()` needs a **different** callback function.  Didn't you notice how I named the function `special` instead of `keyboard`?  And remember, you need to call **both** `glutKeyboardFunc()` **AND** `glutSpecialFunc()`

Comment: sorry there is little bit confusion .so basically in main it shoul be both like this:     glutKeyboardFunc();   glutSpecialFunc(special); but when i do like this i get error tht saying too few arguments to funtion 'glutKeyboardFunc.

Comment: `glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard); glutSpecialFunc(special);` Remove all the `GLUT_KEY_*`cases from **your** `keyboard` function and move them to a new `special` function as proposed by my answer.

Comment: Appriciate ur help it really was helpful _^_

Comment: @Fox: You must not appreciate his help very much; you didn't accept his answer.